# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name' discord.py

Tags: python, discord

```
Part of the code:

def change_1_letter(word, l, r):
word_a = ""
for s in list(word):
    if s != l:
        word_a = word_a + s
    if s == l:
        word_a = word_a + r
return word_a

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    guild = bot.get_guild(769858357607399443) # it is a valid id, this line does not return `None`
    if emoji.is_custom_emoji():
        emoji_count = discord.utils.get(msg.reactions, emoji=emoji).count
    else:
        emoji_count = discord.utils.get(msg.reactions, emoji = emoji.name).count
    if int(emoji_count) > 1:
        await msg.remove_reaction(emoji, author)
        if emoji == bot.get_emoji(771860972340117545):
            game = "Among Us"
            max_pl = 10
        for ch in guild.voice_channels:
            if change_1_letter(game.lower(), " ", "-") in ch.category.name and "lobby" in\ 
            ch.name.lower() and not len(ch.members) > max_pl:
                channel_party = ch
                break
            await author.move_to(channel_party)
```

The Error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\plays\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", 
line 312, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\plays\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Python\bot2.py", line 146, in on_raw_reaction_add
if change_1_letter(game.lower(), " ", "-") in ch.category.name and "пати" in ch.name.lower() and 
not len(ch.members) > max_pl:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

The function moves you to the first channel of the guild that satisfy all conditions when you add new reaction. All of the channels are inside categories with name that looks like the `game` variable with `-` instead of   (categories in discord don't have spaces in their names).

The error appears because of `change_1_letter(game.lower(), " ", "-") in ch.category.name`, without it, the function works properly. It was working before, but when I made the bot more complicated, it stopped functioning. I can't tell what part of the code made this function running with an error because I was not testing this part of the code for a long time.

SFMBE.

Comment: Seems like `ch.category` is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `ch.category` was returning `None` because one of the voice channels was not inside any category, so when the bot checked this channel, he (it) got `None` from `ch.category`.

Solution can be:

```
for ch in guild.voice_channels:
     if not ch.category == None:
         if change_1_lett...:
             channel_party = ch
             break
```